# Iterating 2 querysets in Django html?

Tags: python, django

I have two querysets. My first Queryset (services) has all of my service objects. My second Queryset (rating_values) has all of my rating values, where each index corresponds to the index in the services Queryset. For example services[1] corresponds with rating_values[1].

How do I loop through these two queries in an html page in django so so that I can display the service name along with the corresponding rating value?

To be clear, services contains service objects and rating_values contains decimal values. I pass the variables like this:

```
return render_to_response('services/display_services.html', {'user': request.user, 'services':services, 'rating_values': rating_values  })
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
{% for service in services %} 
    <p> {{service.service_name}} : {{ corresponding rating_value}} </p>
```

**Edit**
Here is my Service model:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    user_id= models.IntegerField(default=1)
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.service_name
```

Here is my Rating Model:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    service_id= models.IntegerField(default=1)
    service_name= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number_of_ratings = models.IntegerField()
    total_rating_value = models.IntegerField()
    rating_average = models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.service_name
```

Comment: Why would you not have a relation between the two tables that allows you to access one from the other already?

Comment: Can you add some information about models? I think you can construct one query which returns all the data for iteration? Otherwise you can manually construct mappings as Python OrderedDict in your view code, before passing it to the template. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Ok, I'll add my Service model and Rating model.

Comment: If the size of both these querysets is going to be the same, and since you don't have any relation between them, you can also pass their size as a parameter and loop through the range in template while printing each of them. I am not sure if there's a better solution.

Comment: it's also redundant and brittle to be having `service_name` field duplicated on the `Rating` model (I realise can be done sometimes as deliberate [denormalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization)) ...just make an actual relation between the tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can establish the relationship right in the model.

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    service= models.OneToOneField(Service, primary_key=True)
    service_name= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number_of_ratings = models.IntegerField()
    total_rating_value = models.IntegerField()
    rating_average = models.FloatField()
    ....
```

You can then pass `services` and get the corresponding ratings..

```
{% for service in services %} 
    <p> {{service.service_name}} : {{ service.rating.rating_average }} </p>
```

Comment: This will not work. `service.rating` does not exist. With a foreignkey in Rating you'll have `service.rating_set` instead. 
A better example would be to loop over ratings, and access `rating.service`

Comment: well, OP wanted to loop over `services`... you could still do `{{ service.rating_set.get.rating_average }}`... or possibly it should be a `OneToOneField` though it's not clear from question

Comment: Haken - Based on the columns, I was thinking this should have been a one-to-one model instead. will edit the post.

Comment: I think the template code will work if you use a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#ref-onetoone) instead of ForeignKey for Ratings.service.

Comment: looking again at the models it does seem a `OneToOneField` would be appropriate

Comment: Made the Changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just to answer the original question as well.

If you for some reason don't want a database relation between the models, you could convert the querysets to lists and zip them in the view, turning the querysets to a list of tuples.

#### view:

```
return render_to_response(
    'services/display_services.html',
    context_instance={
        'user': request.user,
        'services_and_ratings': zip(
            services.all(),
            rating_values.all()
        )
    }
)
```

#### template:

```
{% for service, rating in services_and_ratings %} 
    <p> {{ service.service_name }} : {{ rating.rating_average }} </p>
```

Comment: Learnt something new. What happens if a service does not have any rating? [service=['s1','s2','s3'],rating=['r1','r3']]. Zip seems to mix up services and ratings in that case.

Comment: The two querysets should have equal lenght. The zip object will only be as long as the shortest input iterator. Extra elements in the longest input will be lost.

Comment: Zip is not very suitable to use on django querysets. This was only meant to show that it is possible to do.

The most useful part here, is that you can loop over several variables at once in Django templaes, using tuple unpacking.